# SSAS Calculated measure to show values only for specific dimension values

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have a calculated Measure in my SSAS cube, which I want to calculate only for a group of dimension members and for rest it should be zero. In The following image I want MTDOccupancy dimension to work only for Account Groups for Rooms, rest related to food should show zero for this field.
[image]

following is the simple MDX which I am using for MTDOccupancy measure

```
([MTDQuantity]/[MTDAvailableRooms])*100
```

Comment: `select * from tablename where AccountGroup like 'ROOMS%'`

Comment: @tinka that is sql not mdx

Comment: Go for a cube measure not a calculated measure and use the `SCOPE` operator to set the value as `NULL` for the required members. It is faster than calculated member approach since it is cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the measure to something like the following:

```
IIF(
    LEFT([Account Group].[Account Group].currentmember.member_caption,5) = "ROOMS"
  ,([MTDQuantity]/[MTDAvailableRooms])*100
  ,NULL
)
```

I have guessed this dimension/hierarchy combination `[Account Group].[Account Group]. ...` - you will need to change this to reflect the names used in your cube.

Answer (score 0):

Please do it as a scope statement for performance reasons. The following will get evaluated the first time someone connects to the cube vs the LEFT running in every cell at report time:

```
Create member CurrentCube.[Measures].[My Calc] 
as null
,format_string="0.0%";

scope(Filter([Account Group].[Account Group].[Account Group].Members,   LEFT([Account Group].[Account Group].currentmember.member_caption,5)="ROOMS")); 
   [Measures].[My Calc] = iif(MTDAvailableRooms=0,null,([MTDQuantity]/[MTDAvailableRooms])); 
end scope;
```